# 3D Setting in pst-diffraction not working

Tags: pstricks

The following code should output an image similar to this one from the manual
[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-3d}
\usepackage{pst-diffraction}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-2.5)(3.5,3.5)
\psdiffractionRectangle[IIID=true,Alpha=30,f=2.5,colorMode=1]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it does not render anything in the pdf. I am using XeTeX and Lyx. (Also another minor question, when copy pasting code into a textbox to ask a question on the stackexchange, is there a way to have the 4 spaces come up before every line or do I have to manually add it)

Link to package: [here](https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-diffraction/pst-diffraction-docE.pdf)

Comment: Wild guess: where to get the data from?

Comment: Sorry I should've added a link to the package documentation if that is what you are referring to

Comment: Useful, but I think the images have some data  / measurements that give the values and I think these are needed. At first glanceI did't see the data in the pdf either so probably it is in one of the sites / papers mentioned.

Comment: The other diffraction images work and render as expected, it is only when the option IIID is true that it does not render. Hence I do not believe there is a deficiency in data

Comment: Interesting observation, also the plain `IIIID` does not work for me. No idea here.

Comment: @albert: There is no data file. It is a mathematical function

Comment: @Herbert OK I understand.

Answer (score 1):

With `xelatex` or `latex->dvips>ps2pdf` or use package `auto-pst-pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-diffraction}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-1)(4,1) 
\psdiffractionRectangle[IIID,a=0.5e-3,k=10,f=10,pixel=0.5,lambda=650,twoSlit,s=2e-3] 
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code listing in the documentation is missing the `IIID`. However, every package has also the source as part of your TeX Distribution, so you can have a look how it was really done.

Comment: `IIID` might be missing in the documentation, but in the question it is present (and it was also present in the tests I ran).

Comment: I ran the above code you proposed and unfortunately it does not work. Also IIID is not missing from the documentation. You will notice that they have two codes underneath each other, and so whenever there is a 3D image they have IIID in the option settings which is the same as how I have set IIID=true

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if I am compiling using XeTeX, there is no need for auto-pst-pdf is there?

Comment: I should have said: `auto-pst-pdf` for a run with `pdflatex`.

Comment: If you get _no_ output, then show your log file.